# Problem about exporting data by the function “savetext”

Tags: dolphindb

1.The field type defined in the database is double. If the number is too large, the result exported by the function “savetext” is displayed in E-notation, not the original number.

2.The data of double type imported by sqlserver is 10071.18, and the result is correct while querying in the GUI, but it will become 10071.180000000000291 after being exported by the function “savetext”.

Do I have to format the double data before exporting it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [fomat](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/f/format.html) function to deal with it, for example:

```py
t=table(1 as id,10071.18 as val) 
saveText(select id,format(val,"0.00") as val from t,"/root/double1.csv")
```